# How to access Post Archive created by Elementor?

Tags: plugins, templates

I've created Post Archive template using Elementor Pro, but I don't know how to access the page.

When I access `/blog` I'm redirected to the Home.

How can I access my blog page?

Answer (score 0):

Update Your Permalinks Link in the WordPress Settings

Comment: I saved my Permalinks again, but still redirecting me to Home.